# How to prevent that event is emitted from outside?

Tags: node.js, typescript, events, eventemitter

Imagine I had a simple counting process that acts as a default Node `EventEmitter`:

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';

async function sleep(milliseconds: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}

class MyCountingProcess extends EventEmitter {
  public async start() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      this.emit('counting', i);
      await sleep(1000); // just some demo async function
    }
  }
}

const myCountingProcess = new MyCountingProcess();
myCountingProcess.on('counting', (value) => {
  console.log("current value is: " + value);
});
myCountingProcess.start();
```

So far, everything works as intended.

What puzzles me however is that I could very easily disturb this logic by adding another line *outside `MyCountingProcess`* (after `myCountingProcess.start()`) like

```
myCountingProcess.emit(666);
```

Then suddenly, the exact same process would no longer work as intended.

Is this intentional? Or bad architectural design? Or am I using the `EventEmitter` pattern wrong?

It would make much more sense to me if `emit` could only be called *by* the `EventEmitter` (i.e. within it), not *on* it. Or at least if it could be made a `private` method in TypeScript, although that would of course only be syntax.

So what would one usually do to prevent scenarios like this one?

Comment: This is not a flaw in the eventEmitter design.  Its a flaw in your design.  You gave them the eventEmitter object which enables their ability to call any public method on it.  Your subclassed object is still the eventEmitter object.

Comment: Yes, but that was not completely my point about a potential conceptual flaw. Generally, objects should not be able to emit events on other objects in my view.

Comment: You just have a different opinion about how an eventEmitter works, I guess.  That's NOT how the nodejs eventEmitter works at all.  It has a PUBLIC method to emit events - always has.  If you don't want to offer that interface to the public, then don't allow general access to the emitter.  Make your own methods on your own object and keep the emitter object itself private.

Answer (score 1):

Because `MyCountingProcess` is extending `EventEmitter`, it will behave as an EventEmmiter instance, unless you override the event methods.

For your use case, I recommend adding the EventEmmiter as a variable inside `MyCountingProcess` like this:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

class MyCountingProcess {
  #events: EventEmitter

  constructor() {
    this.#events = new EventEmitter()
  }

  public async start() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      this.#events.emit('counting', i);
      await sleep(1000);
    }
  }

  public on(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) {
    return this.#events.on(event, listener)
  }
}

const myCountingProcess = new MyCountingProcess();
myCountingProcess.on('counting', (value) => {
  console.log("current value is: " + value);
});
myCountingProcess.start();
```

Comment: Said another way.  If you expose the eventEmitter object itself to the outside world, they can call any public method on it.  If you don't want them to be able to call public methods on it, then don't give them the object.  Give them your own object with your own limited set of methods they are allowed to call.  This answer illustrates how to do that.

Comment: So I would have to re-declare all methods of `EventEmitter`? Also think of the name: What is an `EventEmitter` - something that emits events, not something that events can be emitted on. I think `emit` should not be part of the `EventEmitter` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Proxy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy?retiredLocale=nl

Since there are many methods that register events, but only one that emits. It is easy to just prevent emits via the proxy, instead of logging you should probably throw an exception so that it is clearly visible to the consumer of the code that it's not working.

```
public eventRegistry(): EventEmitter {
        return new Proxy(this.dispatcher, {
            get(target, prop, receiver) {
                if (prop === 'emit') {
                    return () => console.error("Cannot emit events from the outside");
                }
                return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
            }
        })

    }
```